# How many ways are there to encode the 26-letter English Alphabet into 8-bit binary words?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know that I need 5 bits to represent a character. All the combinations to encode the 26-letter alphabet will be 2^5? How about the 3 bits that remains from 8 bits?

Comment: How many combinations are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $$\frac{256!}{(256-26)!}=110563655683124321179499922879014944086784979346118410240000000$$ ways to assign 26 different codes out of 256 possible codes to the letters of the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pick one 8-bit binary word for A, then a distinct one for B, and so on. For A, you have 256 different choices. For B, only 255 choices remain, since one is already taken. For C, only 254 choices remain, and so on.

Those are all distinct encodings, since if you pick differently during one step, there is one letter with a different code, and hence the two encodings cannot be the same. Thus, you get.

There are thus $8\cdot7\cdot6$ ways to encode the alphabet ${A,B,C}$ with 3 bits. You should now be able to work out how many ways there are to encode A-Z with 8 bits yourself.

Comment: I think there are 26^8 possibilities.

Comment: @MarryM Think this over again, then, and compare with the simplified example I gave.

Comment: We have C:{a,b,c,...}-{0,1};                                              2^8=256 it results that we have Arrangements taken 26 with 256 elements.